# Unable to set special characters in a variable value in a class in flutter dart

Tags: dart

I am unable to set a string with special characters. It is working fine if I only set a string.

I have written this line:

```
static var var1 = "s$kncsfiu(AKdhjkhj^sjffhj&jh%";
```

But it is showing this error:
[image]

Any clues how can I set this variable value in Dart flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is used in strings for when you want to insert the value of a variable directly into your string. If you want to write `$` in your string, you need to escape it like:

```
static var var1 = "s\$kncsfiu(AKdhjkhj^sjffhj&jh%";
```

Or do it with marking your string as a "raw" string which disable features like the `$` variable replacement:

```
static var var1 = r"s$kncsfiu(AKdhjkhj^sjffhj&jh%";
```

For more information, please read the following section in the Dart Language Tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings